# Why the affected user by ID counts always show zero?

Tags: djaty

I've integrated Djaty NodeJS SDK with my project as the following:

```
djaty.init({
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxx',
  apiSecret: 'xxxxxxxxx',
});
```

I started receiving bugs normally but the affected user counts always show zero. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Djaty gets the user data (`userId`, `logon`) from `req.user` but if the user data don't exist inside the `req.user`, you can pass `parseUser()` option as the following:

```
djaty.init({
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxx',
  apiSecret: 'xxxxxxxxx',
  parseUser: req => ({
    // Fetch the `userId` and `username` from `req.session` for example.
    userId: req.session.user.userId,
    logon: req.session.user.username,
  }),
});
```